# OpenCL program works only for the multiple of itemsize

Tags: opencl

I'm new to openCL program and this is the problem I'm facing while executing a simple vector addition.

I have the following kernel code

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)
int main() {
__kernel void vector_add(__global const int *A, __global const int *B, __global int *C) {

    int i = get_global_id(0);
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

I have integrated gpu and amd gpus on my system. I'm trying to perform vector addition on my intel gpu and for which I have installed the intel opencl drivers (i7 3rd gen processor with hd graphics).

I have the below openCL code

```
std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    std::cout << "Total platforms including cpu: " << platforms.size() << std::endl;
    if (platforms.size() == 0) {
        std::cout << " No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    int i;
    const int LIST_SIZE = 50;
    int *A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    int *B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        A[i] = i;
        B[i] = LIST_SIZE - i;
    }
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;

    fp = fopen("vector_add_kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose( fp );
    //std::cout<<source_str<<std::endl;
    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id* platforms1 = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;   
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, platforms1, &ret_num_platforms);

    platforms1= (cl_platform_id*) malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * ret_num_platforms);
    clGetPlatformIDs(ret_num_platforms, platforms1, NULL);

    /*
    *   Platform 0: Intel Graphics
    *   Platform 1 :  AMD Graphics
    */  
    //CHANGE THE PLATFORM ACCORDING TO YOUR SYSTEM!!!!
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms1[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, 
            &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector 
    cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);

    // Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, 
            (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vector_add", &ret);

    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&a_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&b_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&c_mem_obj);

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_item_size = LIST_SIZE; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_item_size = 16; // Divide work items into groups of 64
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
            &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
    int *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, c_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), C, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Display the result to the screen
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", A[i], B[i], C[i]);
    //FREE
   return 0;
}
```

If the LISTSIZE is 50, it prints only till 48 that is 16*3. It prints only the multiple of LISTSIZE and I'm not able to figure out why?.

Comment: The explicitly specified local_work_size
           will be used to determine how to break the global work-items specified by
           global_work_size into appropriate work-group instances. If local_work_size is
           specified, the values specified in global_work_size[0],...  global_work_size[work_dim
           - 1] must be evenly divisible by the corresponding values specified in
           local_work_size[0],...  local_work_size[work_dim - 1].    This is what I found in the specs. But in my other laptop, it works even for not multiple of local work item size.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL kernels execute only for a multiple of the local thread block size (local Range, in your code `local_item_size`), which should not be smaller than 32 and must be a multiple of 2, (so it can be (32, 64, 128, 256, ...). If you set it to 16, half of the GPU will be idle at any time. `global_item_size` must be a multiple of `local_item_size`. You need at least 32 data items for the kernel to function and a lot more for it to yield good performance.

Also the part

```c
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)
int main() {
```

is not OpenCL C code and does not belong in the .cl source file. If it is not too lengthy, you can write the OpenCL C code directly in the .cpp file as a raw string:

```c
const string kernel_code = R"(
__kernel void vector_add(__global const int *A, __global const int *B, __global int *C) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
)";
char* source_str = kernel_code.c_str();
```